# Microphone not recording

Tags: windows-10, microphone

I have a microphone set as default device with normal levels, but it doesn't record anything. Sound works fine. I have windows 10 and it works fine on my other computer. I have reinstalled the drivers, still nothing. This happened after I removed my linux system so I could use the hdd slot it took.
I see following controllers:
High Definition Audio Device
NVIDIA High Definition Audio
NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device

I have absolutely no idea why it isn't working, any ideas?

Comment: What software are you recording with

Comment: How is the microphone pluged in? Is it a headset with one 3.5 mm plug which is pluged into a combi-headset socket (one for micro and headphones)? Or is has the microphone an independent 3.5 mm plug? The reason why I am asking: I use a Dell Ultrabook at work which has one combi-headset socket. It did not work proberly with microphones out of the box.

Comment: It just doesn't work anywhere at all. The microphone indicator in settings shows nothing. It has an independent socket. It did work before.